# EF: Loading related objects of related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can´t find a way to load an object from a DB with all its related objects. Concerning this simplified model (ID-Properties not shown):

```
class MainClass 
{  
    public virtual ICollection<FirstLevelClass> FirstLevelObjects {get; set;}  
}

class FirstLevelClass
{  
    public virtual ICollection<SecondLevelClassA> SecondLevelObjectsA {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<SecondLevelClassB> SecondLevelObjectsB {get; set;}
}

class SecondLevelClassA
{
    public virtual int SomeValue {get; set;}

}
class SecondLevelClassB
{
    public virtual int SomeValue {get; set;}

}
```

The DbContext is on "MainClass"-Objects:

```
public SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MainClass> MainClassObjects {get; set;}
}
```

How can I load an MainClass-object from db with all first- and second-level-objects? I can do:

```
using (var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var MainClassObjects = context.MainClassObjects.Include(p => p.FirstLevelObjects).ToList();

    // ...move objects from the context to program logic...

}
```

but how do I get SecondLevelObjects? I´m missing something like:

```
using (var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var MainClassObjects = context.MainClassObjects.Include(p => p.FirstLevelObjects.SecondLevelObjects).ToList();

    // ...move objects from the context to program logic...

}
```

Is this even possible or do I have to adapt the DbSets in the DbContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be to use Include method's other overload which takes a string like this:

```
var MainClassObjects = context.MainClassObjects
.Include("FirstLevelObjects")
.Include("FirstLevelObjects.SecondLevelObjects")
.ToList();
```

**Update:**

When you're using this method you just need to determine the paths you want to fetch so for updated question you can use this:

```
var MainClassObjects = context.MainClassObjects
.Include("FirstLevelObjects.SecondLevelObjectsA")
.Include("FirstLevelObjects.SecondLevelObjectsB")
.ToList();
```

Comment: In fact, if you use line Include("FirstLevelObjects.SecondLevelObjects")
you don't even need to use Include("FirstLevelObjects")

Comment: I even tried that before, but it didn´t work at all. I couldn´t even include FirstLevelObjects only. Maybe I was missing something, I will try again.

Comment: It works now, I have no idea what I was missing before. Thanks! But also using this way, I´m nit quite sure how to include two List-Properties of one object. (See updated question).

Comment: Your edited answer (with two different `SecondLevelObjects`) works perfectly, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using (var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var MainClassObjects = context.MainClassObjects.Include(p => p.FirstLevelObjects.SelectMany(s => s.SecondLevelObjects)).ToList();

// ...move objects from the context to program logic...

}
```

You should add a `.Select()` statement to get an object or a list.

Comment: this works so far, thanks! `.SelectMany()` gives an ArgumentException although `SecondLevelObjects` is a list. `.Select` does the job. but now I´m facing another problem: how do I include two "List-Properties" in one class? (Question above updated)

Comment: My bad, it also should be `.Select()` for a list. Answer updated.